# Bash - expanding variables names within variable names

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In a simple for loop, I'm trying to get it to increment which variable it echos.  The unrolled version at the bottom works and does what I want, but how can I get the loop to work the same way?

```
for x in 0 1 2 3 4 do 
       echo -ne $FVAR$x ":: "
       echo $LVAR$x 
done





        echo -ne $FVAR0 ":: "
        echo $LVAR0
        echo -ne $FVAR1 ":: "
        echo $LVAR1
        echo -ne $FVAR2 ":: "
        echo $LVAR2
        echo -ne $FVAR3 ":: "
        echo $LVAR3
        echo -ne $FVAR4 ":: "
        echo $LVAR4
```

Comment: Bash supports array variables.  If your index `x` is a simple integer, that may be something you could consider, referencing them as `${FVAR[0]}` or `${LVAR[4]}`, etc.

Comment: Given this context, that's fair.  The only trouble is the code I'm supporting uses variables in this way because earlier on, exporting must be done, so arrays aren't an option.  I should have specified that in the question, but I am hoping to find some way to just have echo see that $FVAR$x should mean $FVAR0 on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `bash` manual:-

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection.  Bash uses the
>   value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is
>   used in the rest of  the
>   substitution,  rather  than  the  value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.

So you need to store the name of the variable you want to expand in a separate variable, eg:-

```
for x in 0 1 2 3 4
do  fv=FVAR$x
    lv=LVAR$x
    echo ${!fv} ":: " ${!lv}
done
```

You could alternatively define `fv` and `lv` as of type *nameref*: the code would be similar, except that there is no need for `!` to expand the variables:-

```
declare -n fv
declare -n lv

for x in 0 1 2 3 4
do  fv=FVAR$x
    lv=LVAR$x
    echo $fv ":: " $lv
done
```